# Run a python script using ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I am getting troubles to execute a python script using ansible.

I have the next ansible structure:

```
python_project
  roles
    prueba
      files
        prueba.py
      tasks
        prueba.yaml
```

My yaml is the following one:

```
- name: prueba script python playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: run prueba.py
      script: prueba.py
```

I execute it like this: ansible-playbook prueba.yaml and I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or
access 'prueba.py'\n
Searched in:\n\t/root/python_project/roles/prueba/tasks/files/pr                                                                             ueba.py\n\t/root/python_project/roles/prueba/tasks/prueba.py\n\t/root/python_pro                                                                 ject/roles/prueba/tasks/files/prueba.py\n\t/root/python_project/roles/prueba/tas                                                                             ks/prueba.py on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect th                                                                             e file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an issue in the definition in your role. Is that a role and you want it to work as an ansible role? If thats the case you should change a few things.
You should have a separate playbook to invoque this role and move this role to your role folder.
If thats not a role. Indeed you have to specify the path to the python script:

```yaml
    - name: prueba script python playbook
      hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - name: run prueba.py
          script: /root/python_project/roles/prueba/files/prueba.py
```

I think you want to work with roles. To make it as a role you need to change few things.
tasks/main.yml (This is your task directory you can create the yml with the name you want not necesary main.yml)

```yaml
- name: run prueba.py
  script: prueba.py
```

As you can see on a role, the tasks/main.yml dont need to have the hosts, neither the tasks section the file itself its a task section. The logic of the hosts will be moved to the play that invoque the role.

Create this file on any path you want:
example_role_invoque.yml

```yaml
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: invocar rol
        include_role: prueba
```

I let you a reference  link:
[ROLES](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#including-roles-dynamic-reuse)